# How can I convert my report into pdf without using a gridview (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, pdf, pdf-generation, itext

I was able to convert gridviews into pdfs but now I want to generate a pdf for my pay slip.

It has a different format because I fixed the layout using an HTML table, and ASP Labels.

How can I convert that into PDF?

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a built tool for converting to PDF (like teleriks builtin methods for exporting RadGrids to PDF) I'd go for generating the PDF by hand.

Instead of trying to parse the UI into a PDF you can construct the PDF directly from the data source. I've used [iTextSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/) for composing PDF:s manually. It's a bit clunky but it get the job done. Beware of the license for iTextSharp version > 5 if you have a commercial site.

Comment: I am already using iTextsharp but it won't show the HTML part of my codes.

Comment: There is no built in translation between HTML and PDF. You have to make the translation yourself. Or am I misunderstanding the problem here?